# Developing Android with other IDE rather than Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, qt, ide

Hi all
I want to start Android development but I just don't like Eclipse. (Yes, I am picky. lol)
Is there any other good IDE rather than Eclipse that really WORKS with Android SDK? (QT maybe?)

Thanks in advance

Ignacio

UPDATE:
I am on Mac OS X. Is there any plugin for Xcode that makes the trick of linking Android SDK with it?

Comment: QT is an IDE? As for your question, what platform are you talking? What IDE would you consider? On Windows, people have been using Visual Studio, but you'll need to tinker a bit to make that work.

Comment: As far as I know there's no QT plugin for java.

Comment: There is, there is even a specific experimental implementation for Android: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)

Comment: Still, Qt is not an IDE but a toolkit. If you mean Qt creator, that can be useful if you do native development, but not for Java/Dalvik (It supports C/C++ but not java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, my personal experience shows that Netbeans Android plugin (aka nbandroid) is too buggy. I'm using [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) - which is fantastic

Comment: +1 I'm also on Mac OS X, was on WinXp before, I've used all Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ for general Java dev and also for Android. IMHO IntelliJ (CE 10, it's also free) is most advanced and stable, nice syntax highlighting and completion for xml resource files, integrated vcs (svn, git, cvs). Eclipse is too unstable (problems with automatically cleaning projects properly, often unable to kill running tasks, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As for IDEs, Netbeans is pretty good for Android development.

Basically, every text editor or IDE can be used with some amount of tweaking. See this reference as a way to get started: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

**Update:** A page dedicated to alternative IDEs was removed from Android dev guide. A page about workflow & tools has some information on the subject: http://developer.android.com/tools/workflow/index.html#ThirdParty

Comment: The http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html link was not found. Other text books also refer this site but it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: That page was removed from Android dev guide. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is just a terrible, buggy pile of garbage from top to bottom, and most people have told me NetBeans doesn't have a mature Android implementation.

How difficult is it to setup Intellij IDEA for Android development, and what should I expect versus developing for Android on Eclipse?

Comment: -1. This answer doesn't provide any insight at all. In fact, it's another question! Besides, Eclipse isn't that bad once you get used to it. Sure, you may not want to compare it to a professional package like Visual Studio, but I've gotten used to it, even though I use VS in real life.

Answer (score 0):

I advise Android bundle for TextMate: https://github.com/nesterow/Android.tmbundle It's lightweight and easy to use. There is no intellisense, but actually it just makes you remember namespaces better. :)