# What are some some good java IDEs for android?

Tags: java, android, ide, game-engine

I want some good IDEs for android. Eclipse is too slow for my machine. I will soon be moving into game development so I also want to know some good 2d game engines.

Comment: Please, don't ask 2 separate questions at once. It is misleading for those who search for answers on similar questions.

Comment: as arrogant as it may sound but stackmonster is right, eclipse is very good and most desktop pcs can handle it. If you want to get into game dev, you will ned a faster pc anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing Android with other IDE rather than Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961892/developing-android-with-other-ide-rather-than-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

I use [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It's pretty OK. They have support for Android in the free Community Edition now.